# Weird Subversion behaviour on virtual machines

Tags: svn, virtual-machines

I've deployed four virtual machines to test a Subversion setup with specific client and server side hooks. I have one Fedora top level server, Windows working both as client for Fedora server and a server for others, Fedora and Windows machines both clients for above Windows server. It's a simple two rank system.

Windows part got working with no trouble at all. Everything is running fine via SSL.

Fedora based SVN server however works very strange. It works normal locally: via svn, https and even http. But is completely invisible (could not connect to server) for all outside machines. I mean regarding SVN related protocols (svn, ssl, http), SSH of course is available.

The thing is, the system I'm modeling in virtual environment works fine on a real hardware in a local network (192.168.1.*).

I'm using VMware. Every virtual machine got its address dynamically: 172.16.27.129 - 131. Iptables on Fedora server is basically clean. I have no idea where to look further.

The question is, what am I missing? Where should I look?

Answer (score 0):

It was iptables all along. I've copied string allowing port 22 access in /etc/sysconfig/iptables two times: each for 80 and 443, restarted iptables and everything works great now.